Visual Basic (Visual Studio) Array function
I would like to understand if it is possible to put 3 separate functions in arrays as in the example:
Public Class Form1

Dim Data_Out As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Attention 
    'These instructions are not true, they are only used to explain the problem!

    'Array funciont:

    'Process(2) as Function

    'Process(0) = Function_A
    'Process(1) = Function_B
    'Process(2) = Function_C

End Sub

Private Sub Function_A(Data_A As Integer, Data_B As Integer)

    Data_Out = Data_A + Data_B

End Sub

Private Sub Function_B(Data_A As Integer, Data_B As Integer)

    Data_Out = Data_A - Data_B

End Sub

Private Sub Function_C(Data_A As Integer, Data_B As Integer)

    Data_Out = Data_A * Data_B

End Sub

End Class

I would like to understand if it is possible to do this.
Initialize a variable in an array and "transport" the single function with its parameters.
All 3 functions have the same and not different input parameters.
Can it be done?
Can it also be done with functions with different input parameters?
Thank you and everyone for the help!
I tried to search the net but I didn't find anything. :(

Your question can't be VBA and Visiual Studio. I assume your language is VB.Net. Please set your tags accordingly. If your question is not specificly about VStudio 2012 (a pretty old version, btw), remove that tag.

A VB.NET Function should Return data. Creating a class-level variable and manipulating it in several Subs/Functions is bound to lead to errors.

.NET allows you to create delegates, which are basically objects with a reference to a method. You can pass a delegate around like you can any other object, then you can invoke the delegate to execute the method it refers to. This is how you can execute methods in places that don't know anything about the object of which the method is a member.
One of the most common uses for delegates is for handling events. An event is basically a collection of delegates. Registering an event handler involves creating a delegate for the method that will handle the event and passing that to the object that raises the event. When the event is raised, each delegate is invoked and the event handlers executed.
In your case, you could do this:
Dim methods(2) As Action(Of Integer, Integer)

methods(0) = AddressOf Function_A
methods(1) = AddressOf Function_B
methods(2) = AddressOf Function_C

methods(0)(2, 3)

MessageBox.Show(Data_Out.ToString())

methods(1)(2, 3)

MessageBox.Show(Data_Out.ToString())

methods(2)(2, 3)

MessageBox.Show(Data_Out.ToString())

You'll see that that will execute each method in turn. You can even place breakpoints on those methods to see them executed in the debugger.
The framework already contains many delegate types and you can also define your own, but it's simplest to use either an Action or Func delegate in most cases. You use an Action for methods that don't return a value, i.e. a Sub, and you use a Func for methods that do return a value, i.e. a Function. Both can have up to 16 generic type parameters, so can support methods with up to 16 parameters. In the example above, your methods don;t return a value and have two parameters of type Integer, so I have used the Action(Of Integer, Integer). If, for example, you were dealing with methods with parameters of type Double, Integer and String that returned a Boolean, you would use a Func(Of Double, Integer, String, Boolean). Etc.
I suggest that you do a bit of reading about delegates in general. Lambda expressions also create delegates, but they create delegates for anonymous methods rather than named methods. They are used a lot in LINQ but also elsewhere.

Thank you! I answered you below!
I can't get the code to work using the "Func" statement

@MizzardNet7Net7 Func(Of Integer, Integer, Integer). The signature includes the return type, and the argument types

@MizzardNet7Net7, please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how this site works. It is a Q&A site, not a forum. You ask one question and then people provide an answer to that question. You don't post an answer in response to an answer. If discussion is required, you post a comment on the answer and, if appropriate. update your question. You say "I've tried it and it works", which means that this answer addresses the question you actually asked, so accept it and move on. If you now have a new question, post it as a new question, not an answer on this question.
